# Accessing nested json in ExpandRow of bootstrap table react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a bootsrap table react component and I will like to add the nested json record as a table when each row in the bootstrap table, the row should expand and show the nested json has a table. However, I can not access the nested json in the expand row function.

My Goal: Presently I have a table showing the data of the outer json in a table. However, I want the elements in the the nested json summary to be represented in a table when each row is clicked.

```
    const userList = [
      { id: 1, firstName: "james", lastName: "smith", age: 20,summary:{city:'lag', min:12} },
      { id: 2, firstName: "alex", lastName: "green", age: 20 , summary:{city:'lao', min:121}},
      { id: 3, firstName: "may", lastName: "jones", age: 18, summary:{city:'dag', min:112} }
    ];
    
columns=[
{text:'id',dataField:id},
{text:'firstName',dataField:id firstName},
{text:'lastName',dataField: lastName}
]
    
    const expandRow = {
      renderer: row => (
        <BoostrapTable data={userList} columns={row.columns.summary}/>
      )
    };
    
    <BoostrapTable data={userList} columns={columns} keyField="id expandRow={ExpandRow}/>
```

Comment: which package are you using for BootstrapTable?

Comment: I am using bootsraptable from bootsraptable next version 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong variable, it's not rows, but row:

```
const expandRow = {
  renderer: row => (
    <BoostrapTable data={[row.summary]} columns={{text:'city',dataField:'city'},
{text:'min',dataField:'min'}}/>
  )
};
```

Comment: This returns all the json response for the key summary, however I will like to access the data in row.columns.summary.city and row.columns.summary.min. But it returns nothing when I try accessing the data in the nested summary json

Comment: Your question is really not clear. You should post what is userList, and explain better what you would like. The variable row contains the data that you want, but you are using it as columns and not data. What are you tryin to achieve?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: If you want in the expanded row a table with city and min of each user, try the new code, I updated the answer.

Comment: The above does not work. I get an error saying can not read properties of undefined ('reading filter')

Comment: there is no filter in the new code. Where the error is located?

Comment: that's my error. The new code does not return anything in the table. The table is empty. Only the header shows.